# Are questions about genetics more suited here or cross validated if the underlying problem is probability?

Tags: discussion

This is my first meta post, so bear with me if this question needs tweaking. I have the following problem which I needed guidance with:

> Person $P$ carries at least one copy of an autosomal allele of interest. Let $p$ denote the probability that the allele is found at this locus chosen from a random chromosome in the population. Find the probability that a sibling shares at least one copy of this allele with you.

This problem really requires two tasks

- Work out what the underlying probability question is using knowledge from genetics;
- Solve the underlying question involving conditional probability.

Say I have made an attempt to solve the problem, but I'm not completely sure if I have abstracted it right, or if my probability is correct. I see two approaches I could take here, and I was hoping for the community's opinion on which is more suitable.

The first is to ask on biology.SE if my abstraction of the problem is correct or ask for help doing so, and then if I cannot solve the underlying problem due to my probability skills, post on Cross Validated for help.

The alternative approach is to ask the question on one of the sites and hope that the statisticians over at Cross Validated have some knowledge of genetics, or post the question here.

My gut instinct is that the problem is actually better suited here, since probability and statistics are widely used in biology. However I was unsure if the community would appreciate a question where the bulk of the question is about probability.

What approach is most appropriate to asking this sort of question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probability theory is an important part of understanding genetics. Part of being a biologist and practicing biology is being able to solve simple probability questions. Thus, I think simple probability-based genetics questions are suitable to ask on the Biology SE.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that there are two questions here. One is how to formulate the question in probabilistic terms. The second is how to answer that probability question.

So, one option would be to ask the first question on Biology SE, and the second on Cross Validated. However, if the second question was not too statistically/mathematically difficult or complex, the whole thing could be asked and answered on Biology SE.